# How to list all commits that changed a specific file?

Tags: git, commit

Is there a way to list all commits that changed a specific file?

Comment: Are you looking for changes to a file across a single branch; across all local branches; across all branches on a single remote; or across it all? I think across it all will require a script.

Comment: `git log filename`

Answer (score 1489, accepted):

The `--follow` works for a particular file

```
git log --follow -- filename
```

**Difference to other solutions given**

Note that other solutions include `git log path` (without the `--follow`). That approach is handy if you want to track e.g. changes in a **directory**, but **stumbles when files were renamed** (thus use **`--follow filename`**).

Comment: This is better, it seems to list the commits concerning the file across all commits unlike just ` git log <somepath>`

Comment: +1 `--follow` accounts for renames, so this is more robust than `git log -- path`

Comment: Note that `--follow` accepts a _path_, which can be a file but also a directory. In the case of the latter it will run recursively and report changes to all files below that point. (This behaviour is not documented in the manpage and may not be permanent.)

Comment: @SaulOrtega, `git log filename` doesn't follow file renaming, i.e. it will show all commits regarding that **filename** (not actual file). If you create files `X` and `Y`, changed both, then deleted `Y` and renamed `X` to `Y` and then also changed it, and you run `git log Y`, you will get messages for both _old_ `Y` and _new_ one. And the opposite, with `--follow` you will get commits regarding that file when it was named `X` _and_ when it was named `Y`.

Comment: use "git log --all filename" for view all commits in all branches

Comment: Any way to do this using the GitHub API for a particular file?

Comment: @AbhishekSoni That seems to be a new question.

Comment: Does this command (git log --follow -- filename) view all commits in all branches?

Comment: -- is used in several unix commands to indicate file names. Since --follow is a valid file name in unix, if you wanted to show the logs for that file and types `git log --follow` it would be interpreted as the --follow option, not the file, so you would do: `git log -- --follow`

Comment: use with `-p` to not only list but preview the followed changes.

Comment: the last argument is not really the filename. it should be the full path (absolute or relative) to the file. Just using the filename doesn't return anything since git can't find the file. i.e. `-- src/main/java/hello.java`, not `-- hello.java`

Comment: Agreed with @Hilikus. For example, if you want to search for `hello.java` changes anywhere in the tree, you may use `-- **/hello.java`. Git documentation seems to be utterly underdocumented on this.

Comment: I like your answer better because `--oneline` works whereas `-p` doesn't work for that flag.

Comment: For posterity: In my version of git (`2.33.0.windows.2.7.g2aa9e28d2a.20210908104152`) I have to **not** use the double-dash before the file path, even when looking for a file and not a directory.

Comment: @NikoO: In my version (2.34.1), using that double-dash seems totally optional, but works well if typed.

Comment: For me, `git log --follow -- filename` didn't work because the file was subsequently renamed and I was searching with the old name, but `git log --all -- filename` and `git log --all --first-parent --remotes --reflog --author-date-order -- filename` worked with the former being much faster.

Comment: What's the  `--`?

Comment: @jackrabb1t `git log --follow -- ` ***also*** works for folder. Say `git log --follow -- /path/to/folder`

Answer (score 162):

I have been looking at this closely and all these answers don‘t seem to really show me all the commits across all the branches.

Here is what I have come up with by messing around with the [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) edit view options. This shows me **all the commits for a file** regardless of branch, local, reflog, and remote.

```
gitk --all --first-parent --remotes --reflog --author-date-order -- filename
```

It also works with `git log`:

```
git log --all --first-parent --remotes --reflog --author-date-order -- filename
```

Comment: This is perfect for when someone makes changes but they forget where they commited the changes.

Comment: Very useful. Includes also stash commits

Comment: This should be the prefered answer. The question was to find all commits, this one does.

Comment: Notice that `--reflog` includes commits which were rebased/amended or otherwise discarded. Maybe that should be obvious, but I tried to use this with `git log` and was trying to figure out why I was seeing seemingly duplicated commits!

Comment: I don't get it..the accepted answer by @gabe-moothart shows all parent commits of the commit that creates a file on my test tree - ie commits that don't modify the file. This answer works perfectly on my test repo though.

Comment: However, this only shows the changes for this file in each commit, how to let gitk show all changes (including this file and other files that co-changes)?

Comment: this is a life-saver (should I say "file-saver")) when branch was forcefully rewritten

Answer (score 130):

`git log path` should do what you want. From the [`git log` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
[--] <path>…

Show only commits that affect any of the specified paths. To prevent confusion with
options and branch names, paths may need to be prefixed with "-- " to separate them
from options or refnames.
```

Comment: Does not work if the file's path has changed.  jackrabbit's answer does work for this case.

Comment: This works if you need to restrict the log to a specific branch

Answer (score 52):

Use the command below to get commits for a specific file:

```
git log -p filename
```

Comment: I understand that this doesn't exactly answer the question since he wanted a list of commits but this is gold and going in my file.

Comment: This won't work at all if the file doesn't exist in the currently checked-out branch. You can add the branch like `git log -p mybranch -- filename` or just use `git log --all -- filename` to look in all branches.

Comment: for some reason the `log --follow` solutions above were giving me false information (more commits than there should have been). This solution `git log -p filename` gave the correct information.

Answer (score 43):

It should be as simple as `git log <somepath>`; check the manpage (`git-log(1)`).

Personally I like to use `git log --stat <path>` so I can see the impact of each commit on the file.

Comment: Or even `-p` if you want to see the full diff, not just that it had some number of lines modified.

Comment: True, but that's pretty noisy considering most files have been changed many times over their lives. I don't want to see full diffs of every single commit that ever touched a file. I'm usually looking for a specific thing, so I can get a log with just impacts and then `git show` on the specific commits that look like they matter.

Comment: git log --stat --follow -- *.html => output list of commits with exactly one files in each commit. Very nice!

Answer (score 28):

Alternatively (since Git 1.8.4), it is also possible to just get all the commits which has changed a specific **part** of a file. You can get this by passing the starting line and the ending line number.

The result returned would be the list of commits that modified this particular part. The command goes like:

```
git log --pretty=short -u -L <upperLimit>,<lowerLimit>:<path_to_filename>
```

where `upperLimit` is the `start_line_number` and `lowerLimit` is the `ending_line_number`

More Info - https://www.techpurohit.in/list-some-useful-git-commands

Comment: The link is broken: [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol): *"techpurohit.com has expired and is parked free"*. [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS): *"An error occurred during a connection to www.techpurohit.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR"*

Answer (score 19):

As [jackrabb1t pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/how-can-i-list-all-commits-that-changed-a-specific-file/8808453#8808453), `--follow` is more robust since it continues listing the history beyond renames/moves. So, if you are looking for a file that is not currently in the same path or a file that has been renamed throughout various commits, `--follow` will track it.

This can be a better option if you want to visualize the name/path changes:

```
git log --follow --name-status -- <path>
```

But if you want a more compact list with only what matters:

```
git log --follow --name-status --format='%H' -- <path>
```

or even

```
git log --follow --name-only --format='%H' -- <path>
```

The downside is that `--follow` only works for a single file.

Comment: `--follow` works for a single _path_, which could be a directory. If passed a directory it will run recursively and report changes to all files below that point.

Answer (score 19):

To get all commits for a specific file use:

> `git rev-list HEAD --oneline FileName`

For example

> `git rev-list HEAD --oneline index.html`

Output

```
7a2bb2f update_index_with_alias
6c03e56 update_changes
e867142 Revert "add_paragraph"
```

See gif image[image: git commits for specific files]

Answer (score 14):

If you want to look for all commits by `filename` and **not by** `filepath`, use:

```
git log --all -- '*.wmv'
```

Comment: True but that's a glob so it will show all files that match the glob which is not a specific file unless there is only one such file. So yes..but no. (It's not a filename but a glob.)

Answer (score 14):

If you wish to see all changes made in commits that changed a particular file (rather than just the changes to the file itself), you can pass `--full-diff`:

```
git log -p --full-diff [branch] -- <path>
```

Comment: or without the `[branch]`

Comment: @Anentropic The square brackets were supposed to indicate that the argument is optional.

Comment: It's all that I need, It shows full change, includes some change from the merge.

Comment: THANK YOU, this needs more upvotes. `git log --full-diff --stat -- <path>` was the command I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 11):

If you are trying to **--follow a file deleted** in a previous commit, use

```
git log --follow -- filename
```

Comment: For `git` newbies: Use `git log -p --follow -- filename` to display the changes as well.  Also note:  "filename" can be a file, a directory or a submodule.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to view all the commits that changed a file, in all the branches, use this:

```
git log --follow --all <filepath>
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `git log --all <filename>` to view the commits influencing `<filename>` in all branches.

Answer (score 4):

```
gitk <path_to_filename>
```

Assuming the package "gitk" is already installed.

If it is not installed, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install gitk
```

And then try the above command. It is for Linux... It might help Linux users if they want a GUI.

Comment: For Windows users, note that `gitk` is bundled with Git for Windows.

Comment: @SorenBjornstad and for users of other platforms it'll do nothing as well since `apt-get` is debian based, not universal.

Answer (score 4):

To just get a list of the commit hashes, use [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list):

```
 git rev-list HEAD <filename>
```

Output:

```
b7c4f0d7ebc3e4c61155c76b5ebc940e697600b1
e3920ac6c08a4502d1c27cea157750bd978b6443
ea62422870ea51ef21d1629420c6441927b0d3ea
4b1eb462b74c309053909ab83451e42a7239c0db
4df2b0b581e55f3d41381f035c0c2c9bd31ee98d
```

Which means five commits have touched this file. It's in reverse chronological order, so the first commit in the list `b7c4f0d7` is the most recent one.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can use [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) for this.

It can be installed using "sudo apt-get install git-gui gitk". It can be used to see commits of a specific file by "gitk <Filename>".

Answer (score 1):

```
# Shows commit history with patch
git log -p -<no_of_commits> --follow <file_name>

# Shows brief details like "1 file changed, 6 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)"
git log --stat --follow <file_name>
```

[Reference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)

Answer (score 0):

If you use VSCODE, you can use [Git History Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory) or  access TIMELINE as shown below.

[image]