# List all commits (across all branches) for a given file

Tags: git

This question is closely related to [List all commits for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/git-list-all-commits-for-a-specific-file) however it is different. I want to find out which commits, **across all branches**, had modified a given file.

To make it more complex, the given file may or may not be in the working tree.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Try this:

```
git log --all -- path
```

Comment: Nb. you might need `--full-history` option, depending on what you want  exactly to see: see section about history simplification in git-log or gitrevisions manpages.

Comment: Definitely the right answer, assuming you're not wanting to use a GUI.

Comment: This may have changed my life!!!

Answer (score 57):

**Command line**

I would highly recommend to add the graph option with git log:

```
git log --graph --all -- <filename>
```

[image: git log --graph --all -- <filename>]

**Gui**

Gitk is an pretty old tool and not always installed, I recommend a different free tool like e.g. SourceTree:

[image: SourceTree]

Comment: How to log a file and show its branch graph in SourceTree? Right click on a file and select "Log Selected..." doesn't show history on all branches.

Answer (score 56):

You can use gitk

`gitk --all <path to file>   (you need to install gitk)`

e.g.

`gitk --all -- /home/kit.ho/project/abc.txt`

Comment: I don't know why my answer was downvoted, but yours doesn't consider that the question specifically asks for log across all branches. You are just giving answer that the OP has already linked to.

Comment: I wasn't a downvoter, but this needs an `--all` or something similar to go across more history than the current branch.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This works perfectly fine. Both the answers are correct. One works for the text console, the other for the gitk GUI. Can I mark both correct?

Comment: @Saurabh Nanda: Mark the one you think is useful for you.

Comment: @saurabh - This answer has been editted. Kit Ho - Mention that you are editting. And makes it look as though both answers were originally correct.