# how to search for all commits of a particular filename?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List all commits for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/list-all-commits-for-a-specific-file)

I have a very deep git repository in which using my eyes to locate **all commits of a particular file** isn't very practical.

I tried to see if I can grep the output of `git log --all` but there is no trace of any filename there...

How do find all commits in which a particular file actually changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a path to [`git log`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/git-log.html):

```
git log -- path/to/file
```