# Get files from each git commit

Tags: git, github, commit

I have about 160k commits each with 3 files being updated (been using github as a website), and i'm looking for a way to get the files so I can then put the contents into a real DB.

My question is how can I get (download?) the updated files from each commit, saving them to a folder with a timestamp/commitSHA appended to the name to avoid naming conflicts.

Is this possible with git? I know I can use the github site to see the files and what has changed, but the problem is there are over 160k commits.

Comment: what i understand is that you are trying to get every 160k version of the file, is it right?

Comment: Correct. Once I have the files I know what to do with them, getting them is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution but it should work.

First you have to get a local copy of the repository using:

```
git clone <repo-url>
```

You get the `<repo-url>` from the GitHub page of your project (check the "Clone or download" button).

Then you `cd` into the local repo and run something along these lines:

```
for rev in $(git log --format=%H); do
    git checkout $rev -- file1
    cp file1 ../history/file1-$rev
done
```

Make sure you create the `history` directory in advance. Duplicate the two lines inside the loop for each file you need to get.

Run `git reset --hard` at the end to let the repository in its original state.

If you also need the timestamp of the file you can get it using `git log --format=%ct file1`. Replace the `cp` command with:

```
ts=$(git log --format=%ct $rev file1)
cp file1 ../history/file1-$rev-$ts
```

Check the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) for other file or commit properties you can get using [`get log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

Comment: Thanks to all 3 of you (larsks,Fabrizio Migotto, and you axiac). Making this one was correct only because it has all steps.

Now I get to wait while I download 500Kish txt files!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a local working copy of your repository*, you can get the files from any git commit just by checking out that commit, as in:

```
git checkout 1e6c98511d9154bfdc49a31fd26229953df0bd70
```

So, to get the files from every commit in your project history, you would just need to (a) generate a list of commits for your project, and then (b) iterate over that list, checking out each commit and processing the files.

The `git rev-list HEAD` command will generate a list of all the commits on the current branch (from newest to oldest). If you wanted to process these files in forward order, you could pipe that to `tac` to reverse the list, e.g.

```
for rev in $(git rev-list HEAD | tac); do
  git checkout $rev
  ...do something here...
done
```

* by running `git clone <repourl>`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are new with git, you will have to install the git tools from here:

https://git-scm.com/

Then you will have to clone your repository in the git console run:

`git clone https://github.com/username/repositoryname.git`

After these steps you will be able to move in the different commits as @larsks explains.

For listing every commit of a particular file:

[List all commits for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/list-all-commits-for-a-specific-file)