# List all commits that don't include a specific file

Tags: git, commit

It's basically a play on [List all commits for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/list-all-commits-for-a-specific-file) question. I want to list all commits that don't include a specific file (or files). Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

If *don't include* means the file is not changed in the commit, Set A is `git log --pretty=%h --follow <file>`, Set B is `git log --%h`, and `B - A = {sha1 values of commits that don't include the file}`.

```
git log --pretty=%h --follow *file* > a.txt
git log --pretty=%h *file* > b.txt
sort b.txt a.txt a.txt | uniq -u
```

Comment: Well, I'd use `comm` rather than `sort`, but yes. :-)