# Find most recent commit with certain filename

Tags: git

I don't think Git can do this, I feel like I have asked this question before...

Is there a way to search commit history, to find the most recent commit that has a file with a certain name? We renamed or removed a file, and I am trying to recover it / find it.

I get the feeling I will here an answer like "git works off of diffs and not file names.." ok lol thx, but what I am gonna do now lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all commits for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/list-all-commits-for-a-specific-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following command:

`git log --name-only > gitlog.txt`

Then look inside your newly created file (gitlog.txt) using vi or any text editor and use the find feature to search for your filename.

For Example:

I modified filename: `homer/user/git_repo/mytest.py` during a previous commit. 
Lets assume I didn't add the filename to my commit message(usual way)

I would look for it this way using terminal and Unix variant:

`$ git log --name-only > gitlog.txt`
`$ vi gitlog.txt`

while in vi press the `/` key, and type your filename, then press enter. Press `n` to search for more results.

`$ /filename_goes_here`