# How to fetch files from a remote git repository to a local folder, based on specific date?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash, git-log

I am trying to clone/pull, all the files pushed to remote repository, only on a specific date (say, after 2018-08-06). In my remote repository, i have more than 10000 files, but i only need files pushed to the repository, on a specific date. With the below command, i am able to see the logs for a specific time period:

```
git log --since=2018-08-03 --until=2018-08-06
```

Now i need to clone only these files and not all the files in the repository.
Please suggest.

Comment: **git log --name-status --since='3 August 2018' --until='6 August 2018' | grep -E '^[A-Z]\b' | sort | uniq | sed -e 's/^\w\t*\ *//'**

Above command gives the list of filenames.

Comment: "clone/pull" Do you already have a clone of the remote repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to clone or [fetch specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository), only [git objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)
(e.g.: commits).  Also, the changes to each file might be spread among several
commits.

#### Clone

If you do not have a clone yet, make a shallow one:

```sh
git clone --depth 1 "$url"
```

#### Fetch

An option would be to identify locally all files that were modified on this
date range:

```sh
files="$(git log --pretty='' --name-only --since="$since"
  --until="$until")"
```

Then, get [every commit that touches those files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/list-all-commits-for-a-specific-file):

```sh
revs="$(git log --pretty='%H' -- $files | sort -u)"
```

And fetch them:

```sh
git fetch $revs
```

**Note**: This is a naive approach and you might end up fetching a lot of
commits either way.