# List commits that changed a specific file?

Tags: git

Is there a way to list all commits that changed a specific file regardless of HEAD?

I want to include commits on branches that are not reachable from HEAD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all commits that changed a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/how-to-list-all-commits-that-changed-a-specific-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+all+commits+changed+file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `--all` flag to `git log` to look at all branches.
`git log --all --follow --pretty="%H" -- PATH/TO/FILE`

EDIT: Add the `--follow` option to detect renames