# Commit ID of a folder in a repo

Tags: git, gerrit

I've a repo which contains 2 directories

/repo/folder_1
/repo/folder_2

What is the command

- to get the last commit id for the folder_2 changes
- also the modified files in the last commit ?

Comment: Maybe duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3701404/4114120

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all commits that changed a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/how-to-list-all-commits-that-changed-a-specific-file)

Comment: As of now, this command is working for me.

`git log --pretty=tformat:"%H" <required folder path>`

Any other solution?

Comment: So how's the solution in the duplicated question not working for you? If it works for you, why other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two commands for this. First, show the commits on that folder, then show changes according to any commit shown by the first command.

```
git log --follow $YOUR_FOLDER
git show -p $COMMIT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it in a one liner you can do this:

```
# Find the commit of the folder you are interested in
git log -n1 --pretty=format:"%h" --follow $YOUR_FOLDER
# Find all the files that have changed
git show --pretty=" --name-only $COMMIT_ID

# And make it a one liner
git show --pretty="" --name-only `git log -n1 --pretty=format:"%h" --follow $YOUR_FOLDER`
```