# Show specific commits in git log, in context of other commits?

Tags: git

There are various ways to "select" commits with git log. For example:

- [How to list all commits that changed a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/how-to-list-all-commits-that-changed-a-specific-file)
- [How can I view a git log of just one user's commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits)

and many others.

However, all of these show *only* the commits selected for on the command line. What I want is to see all the commits in my range, but *highlight* (with color, or a marker, or whatever) a specific subset of these commits e.g. the commits that changed a particular file or whatever. So when doing:

```
git log --oneline master..@ -- path/to/frobnitz
```

instead of seeing:

```
12ca6d863 foo
6166da1fd bar
894567343 baz
```

I would see something like:

```
46984ad11 (HEAD -> master) git is fun!
2e11a5382 cool beans
>> 12ca6d863 foo
60069036d whatever
d698663d0 something
>> 6166da1fd bar
3d2c811e3 more cool stuff
>> 894567343 baz
3d2c811e3 cool stuff
```

Furthermore, the *ideal* solution would work with `--graph` mode, because I also want to see the merge and branch contexts of the selected commits.

I also note that `git log` supports various [History Simplification](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification) scenarios, which get me almost what I want in some cases, but its not easy to figure out how, nor is it exactly what I want. I already have the history I want to see, and I already have the commits I want to highlight.

Some ideas I had, but I don't like any of them:

- Script it -- run two git logs and then use the output of one to decorate/manipulate the other. The downside of this is that its brittle and it won't work well for different sets of options I might supply to the target log e.g. `--graph`
- For the "selected" commits, assign temporary refs e.g. `selectedcommits` to them, and then use `--decorate-refs=selectedcommits` to show the relevant commits. This seems messy.

Comment: I don't think it is possible using git only.

Comment: That would be a nice feature. Maybe you should submit a feature request the git project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for fun, while waiting for a better answer.

```
git log --oneline --decorate=no --graph | less -p $(git log --pretty=%h -- Makefile | tr '\n' '|')
```

The idea is to pipe the output through, for example, `less` for highlighting specific commits.

[image]

Tested in a bash on Linux and git-bash on Windows.

Here a first try for an alias:

```
[alias] hl-graph = !git log --oneline --graph --color | less -R -p $(git log --pretty=%h \"$@\" | tr '\n' '|') && :
```

Commits to be highlited can be defined as usual:

```
 git hl-graph --since="1 month ago" -- path/to/frobnitz
```

However the log format can't be modified.

Comment: That's a nice hack! Deserves an up-vote, but I won't accept it yet :-)

Comment: For doing this without less/paging, you can also replace `less -p` with `grep -E --color`. And for colored output, append `--color` to the first log command, and either `less -R` or `grep --color` on the second.

Comment: @Raman The alias will be non-trivial if you want to pass agruments to the first **and** the second log command.

Comment: I've added a followup answer with a couple of aliases that focus on the highlighting part, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525740/430128.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the answer by @sergej (upvote it!), and recognizing that the repetitive part of the command which needs to be aliased is really just the highlighting, I've configured these aliases:

```
  hl = "!f() { cd -- ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}; grep --color -E \"$(git log --pretty=%h \"$@\" | tr '\n' '|')\" || true; }; f"
  hlp = "!f() { cd -- ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}; less -R -p $(git log --pretty=%h \"$@\" | tr '\n' '|'); }; f"
```

These are used by piping the output of any log command to the alias. For example:

```
git log --oneline --graph --color | git hl --since="1 month ago" -- path/to/frobnitz
```

(or for the paged version, use `hlp`)

Comment: Hi @Raman, just a note that Git by default [uses `LESS=FRX less`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager) as its pager command, so to get a more "native" feel with your `hlp` alias  I replaced `less -R` with `less -FRX`

Comment: Also, using the `-p`flag of `less` to highlight the patterns means 1) lines before the first pattern are omitted and 2) you are subject to a [bug in `less`](https://github.com/gwsw/less/issues/28). So, as a workaround for both 1 and 2 I use grep to do the highlight and pipe to less at the end: `hlp = "!f() { GREP_COLORS=\"ms=7:\" \\grep --color=always -E \"^|$(git log --pretty=%h \"$@\" | tr '\n' '|' )\" | less -FRX; }; f"`

Comment: and to get bash completion for `log` in the `hl` / `hlp` aliases, you can add ` : git log ; ` ([reference](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7f7ebe054af6d831b999d6c2241b9227c4e4e08d/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L26-L30)) just after the opening `!f() {`

Comment: Also, on macOS `grep` is BSD grep and does not understand `grep -E '^|one|or|two'` to mean "output all lines, but match one, or, and two". But, it works with `grep -E 'one|or|two|$'`, which also works with GNU grep. So an improved version is: `hlp = "!f() { GREP_COLOR=7 GREP_COLORS=\"ms=7:\" \\grep --color=always -E \"$(git log --pretty=%h \"$@\" | tr '\\n' '|' ))$\" | less -FRX; }; f"`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following git command:

```
git log --name-only --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph
```

This command will show all changed files (`--name-only`), the git commit-hash (`%h`), the topic from the command (comment from `git commit command` -> `%s`) and also the branches drawn by different color-lines.

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question. Specific commits shall be decorated.

Comment: @sergej I have changed: now it shows _specific subset of these commits_ (all files where have changed in this commit) or what does he mean with **"a specific subset of these commits"** ?

Comment: All commits shall be shown, but some commits (for example commits touching a file) shall be highlighted.