# Get the git commit base on filename

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have missed one file locally but I can recall I commit and push that file before into the repository.

Can anyone help to get/search that commit base on my file name, so do I can go and get that file again.

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/how-can-i-list-all-commits-that-changed-a-specific-file

Comment: I did not have that file in current branch, will this workout ?

Comment: That I don't know :/ Let me know if it does.

Comment: I tried but nothing came out

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following instruction:

```sh
git log --all --full-history --oneline -- {{YOUR_FILE_NAME}} **/{{YOUR_FILE_NAME}}
```

So you can find the file name in the project history if it were on the root folder, or in any subfolder.

Please tell me if that works for you.

Comment: thanks for response,  I tried but it does not work out for me

Comment: What's the output your received from the above command?

Comment: no console output, command executed with no error