# Listing all later commits from HEAD across branches that changed a file

Tags: git

The question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/how-to-list-all-commits-that-changed-a-specific-file) one with a small change.

Suppose I have checked out commit B:

```
  G
   \
E - F - B (*) - A (first commit)
        /      /
   D - C      /
   H - - - - -
```

So, `HEAD` is B. I would like to only list those commits to the *left* of B (including B), or temporally later than B (or including B) that changed a particular file, `file1.txt`.

There are two subcases -- (1) the commits listed could be only descendants of B so that a later commit whose parent is A that is temporally later than B is not listed (H would not be listed in the example above), (2) the commits listed could be descendants of A on a separate branch yet with a commit date later than B. (H would be listed)

In both subcases, I only want to list commits that affected/changed `file1.txt`.

The linked to question lists all commits that changed the file including A, which I don't want to be listed.

Answer (score 1):

Subcase 1 is fairly straightforward with `--ancestry-path` and `--all`. You could solve Subcase 2 by using a nested command to pass the committer-date of HEAD to `--after`.

Subcase 1 - All descendents of B (HEAD):

```bash
# List HEAD and all of its descendents

git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all \
  --ancestry-path=head head~1..
```

Subcase 2 - List descendents of the parent of B (HEAD) with a later commit time than B (HEAD):

```bash
# List HEAD and descendents of the parent of HEAD.
# Limit by committer-times being after HEAD's.

git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all \
  --ancestry-path head~1.. \
  --after=$(git show -s --format=%ct | awk '{print $1}')
```

Comment: Thank you. The first command results in `fatal: unrecognized argument: --ancestry-path=head` 
Also, there is no argument in the command that takes in the file name: `file1.txt` in the example of the OP.
Version number of git is: git version 2.33.0.windows.2

Comment: @Tryer I didn't include the filename argument from the other answer because it's trivial to add it to the command I gave. I'm just showing you how you would filter the commits by date and ancestry. As for the Windows Git error, I have no way of debugging that.