# How to extract changes to one pathspec from a long history?

Tags: git

I have a repo with several internal projects and project `A` has been improved significantly in the development branch of project `B`. I want to get all those improvements to A and apply them to a clean branch that has none of the other code related to `B`, just the `A` code.

At first I thought I could just merge squash the dev branch into a clean branch and delete out all of the non-`A` code, but if it's possible to save the work, I was hoping there's a way to get commits matching pathspec `src/View` as either a cherry pick or other command to ignore a lot of the dev branch history.

Edit: just to clarify, the "clean branch" would be a dedicated branch to work through any merge conflicts between the `B` version of `A`  and the dev version of `A` before merging this clean branch into `A`, essentially hopefully resulting in a fast forward of `A` to the current improved state as exists in `B` dev branch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need the history? If not you can do `git restore --source=<commit> -- path/to/project/.`, this should be done from the clean branch. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/how-to-list-all-commits-that-changed-a-specific-file combined with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files should be the way to go. Let us know if you run into issues, and we can take it from there.

Comment: @Cristik see cautionary tale in my self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried two methods, one failed horribly, one worked as hoped.

First I tried

```
git checkout A
git merge B --no-commit --no-ff  // Brought all of B's development into A as staged changes
```

Now I would delete all staged applicable to `B`, and leave the staged applicable to `A`. The question is how...we are in the middle of a merge. I managed to footgun myself by using a combination of `git reset` and `git restore` to clear the staged changes of `B`. just the remaining changes applicable to `A` remained staged. I committed. All great. Then I did `git checkout B` and `git merge A`. In theory git would report "nothing changed". Instead, the merge treated the entire dev of B as node removals and completely wiped all files. Except the files applicable to `A`. I had to hard reset and then pull the dev branch from remote which fortunately was up to date.

The second attempt was

```
git checkout A
git checkout B <pathspec>
```

This worked great. I committed this to `A`. Then `git checkout B` and `git merge A` which is the same test as above. It had a merge conflict which was my fault. But definitely the way to go.